# How to dismiss a UIPopover correctly?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uipopovercontroller

i have added a UIPopover to my navigationbar when the user touches the rightbarbuttonitem.
I want to know whats the cleanest coding for showing and dismissing the popover. With the code below, it works, but not correct. 
If the user touches the rightbarbuttonitem first, the popover appears. Now he can choose a cell,.. works. Or you can touch outside the popover and it disappears. Both ways correctly.

But when touching the rightbarbuttonitem and after that, the same touch on that icon again, you have to touch it twice to bring up that popover again. (Not on the first touch).

How should that correctfunction look like? Thanks for your time..

```
 -(void) downloads:(UIBarButtonItem*)button{
        NSLog(@"downloads");
        if(tableViewController == nil) {
        tableViewController = [[[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];

        self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tableViewController]autorelease] ;
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
        tableViewController.delegate = self;
        }else {
            [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
            tableViewController.delegate = nil;
            tableViewController = nil;
            //[self.popoverController release];
            //self.popoverController = nil;
        }
    }

    //delegate
    -(void) selectedTable:(NSString*)text{
        NSLog(@"selectedTable: %@", text);
         [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comments**

Your `downloads:` method checks for `tableViewController` value and make decision if UIPopoverController should be displayed or dismissed. But yours `selectedTable:` method does dismiss `popoverController` and does not set `tableViewController` to nil thus it doesn't work as expected by you.

And I also don't see `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` implementation, especially `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` which will tell you when `UIPopoverController` was dismissed (by touching outside your `UIPopoverController` for example).

**Memory Management**

Read memory management guide. `[self.popoverController release]` with `self.popoverController = nil` leads to crash - one release and second release during setting to nil. (I assume your `popoverController` property retains).

Answer (score 0):

@Chiefly Izzy: Thanks for your help. You point me in the right direction. 
Here´s the code i´m using. It works great. Hope that memory management is clean, too. Isn´t it?

```
-(void) downloads:(UIBarButtonItem*)button{

    if([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible])
    {   
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [self.popoverController.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:self.popoverController];
        return;
    }

    // PopOver Bookmarks-Icon
    if(tableViewController == nil) {

        tableViewController = [[PdfTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]; //autorelease];

        self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tableViewController]; //autorelease] ;
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

        popoverController.delegate = self;
        tableViewController.delegate = self;
    }
    /* Using "isPopoverVisible" from top or that else. both works
     else {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [self.popoverController.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:self.popoverController];
    }
    */  
}

-(void) selectedTableView:(NSString*)text{
    NSLog(@"selectedTableView: %@", text);

    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [self.popoverController.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:self.popoverController];
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popover{
    NSLog(@"popoverControllerDidDismissPopover");

    tableViewController.delegate = nil;
    [tableViewController release];
    tableViewController = nil;

    popoverController.delegate = nil;
    [popoverController release];
    popoverController = nil;
}
```